# How to print stack trace (with symbolic function names) on Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stack-trace

This question has been asked a number of times, but it has never really been answered. I've spent 5 to 6 hours today trying to port some libraries to Android (libunwind, liwdfl) that probably have never been intended to work on ARM. To no avail, of course.

The problem is that Android lacks `backtrace` / `backtrace_symbols` functions. Has anyone found a way to print stacktrace, say, upon receiving SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way this is done internally is with the [CallStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-dev/include/utils/CallStack.h) class.  For example:

```
CallStack cs("logtag");
```

will dump the current native call stack to the log.  Unfortunately this is not available in the NDK, and the class does change from version to version.

In Android KitKit (4.4), the [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-dev/libutils/CallStack.cpp) used the internal [libcorkscrew](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-dev/libcorkscrew/) library.  In the current "master" branch, the [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libutils/CallStack.cpp) uses [libbacktrace](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libbacktrace/), also an internal library.  However, this new library is built on [libunwind](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libunwind/+/master), an [open-source project](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/).

So you should be able to build libunwind into your app and use it that way.  Since the libraries are already in use on Android, porting should be far less of a problem (just start with the AOSP [external/libunwind](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libunwind/+/master) sources).

Comment: I've looked at the `CallStack` class and didn't see a way to compile it without also compiling half the AOSP repository. But I guess I'll give it a try if there's no better way.

Comment: I was thinking it would make more sense to pull external/libunwind out of AOSP and build something CallStack-ish on top of it.  The stuff in "external" generally doesn't have significant dependencies on other things, and you know it's already been ported to work on Android.

Comment: Do you know whether or not it can resolve addresses to symbolic names? Because if not - I shouldn't waste time on it.

Comment: I haven't worked with it myself, but the documentation seems to say it does, e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libunwind/+/master/doc/unw_get_proc_name.man