# Android NDK - display stack trace on demand

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm currently trying to find an easy way to display a stack trace while debugging JNI code.

The closest way I've come to achieving this is by deliberately causing a runtime error (i.e., accessing a member of a struct which has not been initialized). When this happens, I can see a very clear stack trace in the logcat output. The only problem with this is that this also causes the app to stop running. I was hoping to find a way to achieve the exact same thing, but without causing the app to crash.

Comment: There's a library built into the system, but I don't know if it's exposed in the NDK. Dalvik used it to dump the native portions of stack traces; see e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/interp/Stack.cpp#1386 . It evolved quite a bit over time. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308625/